# Rasterio error too many point when reproject from epsg:4326 to Behrmann

Tags: python, coordinate-system, rasterio

I am trying to reproject a raster image with the raster package. The source CRS is EPSG:4326 and the destination CRS is Behrmann obtained from another raster, but I get an error. I leave you the code below and the error:

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from rasterio.warp import calculate_default_transform, reproject, Resampling
import geopandas

route = r"I:\miguel_analysis\AMPHIBIANS_2020_04\RASTER\raster_50x50_2020_05_20_behrmann\Adenomera bokermanni.tif"
src_file = r'I:\miguel_analysis\0_utils\wc_2_1_5m_4326.tif'
dst_file = r'I:\miguel_analysis\0_utils\wc_2_1_5m_berh_rast.tif'

with rasterio.open(route) as src:
    dst_crs = src.crs


with rasterio.open(src_file) as src:
    transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
        src.crs, dst_crs, src.width, src.height, *src.bounds)
    kwargs = src.meta.copy()
    kwargs.update({
        'crs': dst_crs,
        'transform': transform,
        'width': width,
        'height': height
    })

    with rasterio.open(dst_file, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
        for i in range(1, src.count + 1):
            reproject(
                source=rasterio.band(src, i),
                destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
                src_transform=src.transform,
                src_crs=src.crs,
                dst_transform=transform,
                dst_crs=dst_crs,
                resampling=Resampling.nearest)
```

the output is

```
CPLE_AppDefinedError: Too many points (7569 out of 7569) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.
```

the defintion from crs is:

```
       GEOGCS["WGS 84",
              DATUM["WGS_1984",
                    SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                             AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
                    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
              PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
              UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
       PROJECTION["Behrmann"],
       PARAMETER["False_Easting",0],
       PARAMETER["False_Northing",0],
       PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0],
       UNIT["metre",1,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
       AXIS["Easting",EAST],
       AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]
```

Comment: I don't know about the code, that error is common for latitude and longitude exchanged. But you are providing an erroneous CRS definition: a projected CRS which does not start with the PROJCS keyword. I don't know if it is just an error in the question or you need to check the destination CRS WKT string definition about that.